# Approximating a curve for the production rates

Tags: approximation, curves

I am doing graduate research on chemical production rates, and I need to reproduce a logistic decay function. I have an upper and lower limit, 3 points and an inflection point:

Upper limit: $3.3$
Lower limit: $1.2$

3 points: $(7.5, 3.3)$, $(15.258, 1.3)$, $(16, 1.2)$.

Inflection point: $(11.6, 2.25)$.

It seems too easy, but hours of searching the internet (including this site) have yielded no results on how to make this equation. Sorry if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: do you want to fit polynomial in degree 2 ,because you have 3 points ?

Comment: what's wrong with using the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function)?

Comment: @Chester thank you so much, that's what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\hline
\text{Approximation} & \text{Function} \\
\hline
\text{polynomial} & 0.014473825 x^2 - 0.58719371 x + 6.8898002\\
\text{exponential} & 8.0799808\cdot 0.88741028^x\\
\text{linear} &-0.25145441x + 5.1819567\\
\text{logarithmic} & -2.7909806\ln(x) + 8.922503\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$